# Find the close form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$a_0 = 0$ and, for $n > 0$, $a_n =a_{n-1} + 3$ be a recurrence relation. The close form of $a_n$ is:

**A.**  $3(n-1)$

**B.**  $3n$

**C.**  $3(n+1)$

**D.**  $n^2$

I guess is **B** but anyone could explain it for me please?
Thanks

Comment: Try each of them and see which one fits.

Answer (score 1):

It is an arithmetic recurrence so its general term is $3n+a_0=3n$.

You can prove it as follows:

$a_n=a_{n-1}+3$

$a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}+3$

...

$a_1=a_0+3$

Now sum all the previous equations member by member. You obtain:

$a_n=a_0+3n=3n$